# Emacs shell command: Change of behavior between versions 24 and 25?

Tags: shell, emacs, buffer

I have been using the Emacs "shell" command for many years. It starts a shell in the current buffer. This seems to be the case up through Emacs 24.

I am now running Emacs 25 (on Linux) and I'm finding that the shell command works differently. It starts (or goes to) the shell in a different buffer, splitting the current window if necessary. Sometimes the shell goes to the current buffer, sometimes to the other buffer (if I'm displaying two buffers).

What gives? How can I have the shell command work the way it used to?

Comment: You should probably ask this question on the [emacs site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was a change in Emacs 25.  The solution is given in the NEWS file; add to your `.emacs` file:

```
;; display shell in the current window
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("^\\*shell\\*$" . (display-buffer-same-window)))
```

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Please consider hitting the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: NEWS (`view-emacs-news`) is on `C-h n`.